# WordPress Gutenberg react make import of __experimentalUseInnerBlocksProps which is no more experimetal

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, block-editor, import

I have a plugin with import

```
import { __experimentalUseInnerBlocksProps as useInnerBlocksProps } from '@wordpress/block-editor';
```

but it's not working with newest Gutenberg plugin 11.9, because this `useInnerBlocksProps` is no longer *experimental*

so I can use

```
import { useInnerBlocksProps } from '@wordpress/block-editor';
```

but then it will not work for older versions, or WordPress installation without Gutenberg plugin.

What's the correct way to make it compatible with both scenarios? How to import __experimentalUseInnerBlocksProps if exists and directly useInnerBlocksProps if not?

Comment: you should raise this as a bug on their repo ASAP as this will impact WP 5.9

Comment: @TomJNowell it's not a bug, this will happen again, everytime when experimental function is fully developed, tested and prepared to be part of the core

Comment: You may be told that you shouldn't have used the experimental APIs, but nothing prevents them exporting it under both names so that things don't break. It is fixable from their end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is probably the easiest workaround I was able to find, but if someone has better idea, then feel free to post it here ;)

```
import {
    __experimentalUseInnerBlocksProps,
    useInnerBlocksProps,
} from '@wordpress/block-editor';

if( typeof useInnerBlocksProps == 'undefined' ){
    var compatibleUseInnerBlocksProps = __experimentalUseInnerBlocksProps;
}else{
    var compatibleUseInnerBlocksProps = useInnerBlocksProps;
}
```

- so basically I can import both (experimental and no-experimental) without any error
- then I can just do simple type test if the new one is already supported
- if it's supported I will remember it in `compatibleUseInnerBlocksProps` variable
- otherwise I will remember old *experimental*
- then I need to replace all other occurrences of `useInnerBlocksProps` with `compatibleUseInnerBlocksProps` in my code

Answer (score 0):

I used the logic from the [accepted answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/398086/22506), which works great.

But I implemented it a little differently. I import `useInnerBlocksProps` as `nonExperimentalUseInnerBlocksProps`. This way, I can keep using `useInnerBlocksProps` where I use it in the code. This will make it easier to remove support for `__experimentalUseInnerBlocksProps` in the future.

```js
import {
  useInnerBlocksProps as nonExperimentalUseInnerBlocksProps,
  __experimentalUseInnerBlocksProps,
} from '@wordpress/block-editor';

const useInnerBlocksProps =
  typeof nonExperimentalUseInnerBlocksProps == 'undefined'
    ? __experimentalUseInnerBlocksProps
    : nonExperimentalUseInnerBlocksProps;
```